# Visual studio and git: "use" info from another repository?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visualgdb

I have access to a repository on GitHub that hosts C++ source files.  Other people using this repository check out the code and build via the command line with CMake, but I want to add the source files to a Visual Studio project and build/debug using the IDE and a plugin called VisualGDB.

I use VisualGDB to "import an existing CMake project" from this cloned repository: it creates me a VisualGDB project at the location I tell it to, and allows me to build and debug the code it is referencing.  I now want to use the Git integration that is in Visual Studio so I can see pending changes to the source code etc within the IDE, and not need to go to TortoiseGit or the Git bash.

I have pushed my VisualGDB project to my GitHub, and - quite rightly so - when I do so it complains

> "Your solution contains files outside the solution folder which will
> not be included. See the output window for details about which files
> must be manually added later."

The only changes Visual Studio detects are those made to the files that are part of the project (like the .sln and .vgdbcmake) - **is there some way I can "tell" Visual Studio to look at the Git information in the source code repository that I have pulled** so it also "detects" changes to my source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  If I create my VisualGDB project **within the cloned directory**, then Visual Studio can "see" the .git folder and it uses it.

It seems that Visual Studio will use any .git folder in the directories *immediately above* the project directory, but it won't look in any subfolders.  So the problem in my case was that I had a directory structure like this:

```
C:\Code\Visual_GDB_Project
  + VisualGDBProject.vgdbcmake
C:\Code\Cloned Respository
  +.git
  <many source files>
```

...where the vgdbcmake file references the source files in the cloned repository.

When I changed this to be

```
C:\Code\Cloned Respository
  + .git
  <many source files>
  + Visual_GDB_Project
    VisualGDBProject.vgdbcmake
```

Then Visual Studio correctly displays the Git information for the Cloned repository.  I can also add many other projects to my solution, and Visual Studio correctly displays the Git information for all of them, provided I have set "Enable multi-repo support" in Tools->Options->Preview Features.  Note that I am using Visual Studio 2022 Pro.